# How to insert null in column array datatype in ksql

Tags: confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am creating a stream where data type is Array. a null value comes so handle this i am creating another stream on top of previous stream, and giving a case like if its null put []. but its not working.

i have tried [],{},[0],0 in cases.

```
CREATE STREAM stream1
(
id VARCHAR,
tags ARRAY<INT>, 
feed_id VARCHAR,
status INT,
updated_at VARCHAR
)
WITH (kafka_topic='origin_topic', value_format='JSON');

Create Stream stream2 AS 
select  
id AS id,
case when tags is NULL THEN [] END ELSE tags END as tags,
case when feed_id is NULL THEN '0' ELSE feed_id END as feed_id,
case when status is NULL THEN 0 ELSE status END as status,
case when updated_at is NULL THEN '0' ELSE updated_at END as 
updated_at
from stream1 PARTITION BY id;
```

Answer (score 2):

ksqlDB supports an array constructor `ARRAY[]`, though if you're running an old version this may not be available.  Also, it does not *yet* support empty arrays, so you'll need to pass at least one parameter, e.g. `ARRAY[1]` will create an array with a single INT/BIGINT element.